# Full-sized ice cubes

Tags: mathematics, time

On a table in front of you is a small freezer that is capable of holding seven standard ice cube trays stacked on top of each other. There are no shelves to separate the trays, and if you stack one tray on top of another before the ice cubes in the bottom tray are fully frozen, the top tray will sink into the bottom tray and you will not be able to make full-sized ice cubes. You have an unlimited supply of trays, each of which can make a dozen ice cubes.

If it takes fifteen minutes for the water to freeze completely into an ice cube, what is the maximum number of full-sized ice cubes you can produce in sixty minutes?

> As per my calculation, one can do 120 cubes each time. Since it takes
>  15 minutes to make an ice cube, 120X4=480 would be the answer.
>  However, need some validation on whether the maths is correct.

**Edit 1:**

*Seems like a few of us have presumed we are allowed to break or mutilate the trays, unfortunately, it is not part of the deal.*

Comment: can you pls tell how 120 cubes are possible each time

Comment: Yeah, I'm really struggling to see where 120 comes from. The freezer only fits 7 ice cube trays with 12 each so I'd have thought an upper bound on the number of icecubes would have to be 12*7 = 84 every fifteen minutes. You somehow are making 120 every fifteen minutes?

Comment: Fill 4 trays with water and turn the other 3 upside down and use them to space the 4 apart. That gives 48 cubes. Then, empty the 4 trays and put 2 ice-cubes in diagonally opposed corners of each of 6 of the trays. Fill the remaining holes — and the entire 7th tray — with water. Using the ice cubes to hold the trays apart, stack all 7 (the 7th tray should go on top), and freeze them. You get another 72 cubes.

Comment: I got one thing wrong, you can get 72 cubes for every batch except the first, for which spacer ice cubes are not yet available. So, that makes 48+72+72+72=264. Again, not sure, if the maths is correct.

Comment: How come it can only handle 7 trays?  Stacked vertically that is about 10" high and 6 inches wide, that is truly a tiny, tiny freezer.

Comment: How about investing in an ice chipper instead?  Get a hefty garbage bag, rotate freezer upwards, put inside freezer, and fill with water.  Then freeze lift the massive block of ice out, and run it through a chipper.

Comment: You state the freezer can fit 7 ice cube trays, how does unlimited ice cube trays help us since only 7 can fit at once?  Can I just order a custom 3d printed ice cube tray that fits your dimensions exactly?  (bet I can get way more ice cubes.)

Comment: @cybernard the size of the freezer is a premise of the puzzle, it cannot be argued with. Freezers do not work on their side. The tray size is a premise of the puzzle and cannot be argued with

Comment: Don't answer your own question in comments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First produce 48 by putting the traces up/down/up/down/up in the freezer. Then use 18 of the ice cubes and put them in the corners of the botton 6 trays, produce 66 more ice cubes. Do this 2 more times and get 246 in total.
Possibly could make 264 if you can balance using 2 cubes only.

Comment: I believe this is the most efficient without modifying the size/shape of any trays.

Comment: It is written that the freezer can hold only 7 trays, putting cubes at the bottom of trays will increase the height to a double

Comment: @Vikram, this solution is putting 3 ice cubes in 3 ice cube spots in each of the 6 stacked trays below the top tray. Those 3 cubes in each tray act as a triangle base on which the other trays will rest while the other 9 cube slots are filled with water that forms new cubes.

Comment: @Forklift, you are assuming that the cube fit perfectly into the groove

Comment: No, @Vikram, I am assuming the ice cube fits perfectly into the ice cube shaped space in which ice cubes are created.

Comment: @Forklift, not getting what you mean, anyway,this puzzle is ill defined and I flagged it for closure few hours back

Comment: @Vikram, Step 1 - do what you said the first 15 minutes.  Step 2 - put an ice cube from step 1 in 3 corners of 6 trays, fill the other 9 spots with water and stack them.  Fill the 7th tray with water and place on top.  Repeat step 2 two more times.

Comment: @Vikram, I agree there could be some clarification of limitations. If mutilation is allowed, there are better answers.

Comment: in theory you should be able to just use 2 ice cubes in diagonal corners of the trays rather than three. The ice cubes have width so you should have a stable base.

Comment: Got confirmation. 264 happens to be the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Since the freezer can accommodate 7 trays at a time, follow the following arrangement

full tray
upside down empty tray
full tray
upside down empty tray
full tray
upside down empty tray
full tray

So,

> in $15$ minutes $4\times 12=48$ cubes can be made and in $60$ minutes $48 \times 4 = 192 $ cubes can be made

Comment: Hah, I didn't think of that. Nice.

Comment: I love (hate) "out-of-the-box" answers just as much as everybody else. But when the "mathematics" tag is there, IMO, flipping the tray upside-down doesn't fly.

Comment: @Jeffrey,no one cares what you love(hate), if you are so much  concerned about tags, why don't you suggest the OP to include logic,lateral-thinking,calculation-puzzle,strategy,optimization tags.  do you call adding 4 two digit numbers mathematics? it is arithmetic.

Comment: @vikram he's just upset because he can only do mathematics puzzles, not lateral thought ones, and by tagging this one thus the OP has lured him in under false pretences and wasted 10 seconds of his precious time..

Comment: I don't know should I feel amused or be saddened on which way this discussion is going just coz of *tags*

Answer (score 6):

We could freeze more than 192 ice cubes as per @Vikram's answer, IF

> We could cut/break the trays.
>
>  For example, if the ice cube trays are 3x4, we could cut 3 of the trays to be 3x3:
>  [image]
>
>  And then stack the ice trays so that they don't fall into each other:
>
>  3x4
>  3x3
>  3x4
>  3x3
>  3x4
>  3x3
>  3x4
>
>  Side view:
>  [image]
>
>  This gives us $4*4*3 + 3*3*3 = 75$ ice cubes per freezing
>  And $4*75=300$ ice cubes per hour.

Comment: I suppose if you had an unlimited amount of trays you wouldn't mind breaking some ;)

Comment: @BMS21 Indeed :))

Comment: Standard ice cube trays where I come from are 2x6....

Comment: @Hellion Sure, but standard ice cube trays where *I'm* from are also made for stacking so they don't sink into each other ;)

Comment: @SetBigO a very good point.  :-)

Comment: Sorry, but breaking the trays is not part of the deal, i will update the question :)

Comment: @Hellion, you still can cut them and stack them so that they don't fall into each other: 6*2;5*2;6*2;5*2;6*2;5*2;6*2. Wich make 78*4=312 ice cubes par hour.

Answer (score 5):

Since we have unlimited supply of trays(and assuming that selling part of them for infinite money and purchasing more freezers is not an option), I would say that in 1 hour we could freeze maximum of

> 336 ice cubes

ice cubes.

Here's how:

> We cut the very top part of X trays and put a non-cut tray into them as long as the height of the cut parts is not exactly equal to the height of the tray. Repeat this for 5 other trays and now you can stack them on each other without the top ones falling through and breaking the bottom ones.

---

And some pictures:

> So we have such an ice tray(okay, it should be 12-cube, but I was too lazy to search for one:
>  [image]
>
>  And we will cut the part marked red:
>  [image]
>  So we will have a lot of these pieces:
>  [image]
>  Now we only need to cut out enough of these parts to be able to stack trays on top of each other so that trays on top are supported by the trays at the bottom and not on the water/ice itself:
>  [image]

Comment: The trouble is, these would take up space.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 no, they wouldn't. Cut it so that the bottom of these pieces per each tray is just as low as the tray's bottom itself, so that maximum length, width and height of each tray remain the same

Comment: I don't understand how that could be done unless you used up space that the ice cubes should occupy. Theoretically, a freezer with space for 7 doesn't even need to have space for "7 and some air around the sides".

Comment: @wizzwizz4, you just put the cutouts underneath the tray, so that it's bottom surface becomes wider and can support on the top surface of the other tray without falling into it

Comment: Wizzwiz, the suggestion is to cut up X number of trays to make spacers so that the upper tray can sit on top of the lower tray without sinking into it

Answer (score 1):

48

Due to the limitations on placing trays upon partially frozen trays, you can only be freezing 12 cubes at a time. 4*12=48

You can't do 120 cubes at a time, even without the freezing limitation, as it states the freezer can only hold 7 trays, so at best you'd be able to do 84, but that would only be without the placing-upon-unfrozen-trays limitation, which brings it back down to 12 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Tilt the freezer 90 degrees so that the door opens up, fill up the entire freezer, like a tub, with water and trays place vertically. The trays should stay separated because they are not falling into each other now. After 15 minutes, remove the trays and crack out the ice cubes, and repeat 3 more times. 7x12x4 = 336 cubes

Comment: How are you meant to keep the water from sticking multiple trays together? This answer doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Wonder if PAM cooking spray would work?

Comment: The compressor in a freezer won't work if the freezer is tipped in its side, but I appreciate your lateral thinking

Comment: @CaiusJard - could be a solid state Thermoelectric freezer, which should work in almost any orientation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Trick question!

Ice cube trays are designed to stack on top of each other without freezing together. There are pieces on the bottoms of the trays that sit on the top lip of the tray below it, so they don't sink in & freeze together.

So you can put all 7 trays in at once.

12 cubes per tray x 7 trays x 4 batches per hour = 336 ice cubes per hour.